# how to refresh the view controller

Tags: objective-c, view, setneedsdisplay

I have a Class A that when the viewwillAppear finished then I get some data after some seconds from server that according that data I change some buttons on view, is there any way how to refresh the view completely in objective -c?

Answer (score 0):

Just reload elements on your UI that should be reloaded. Propably you are doing something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
}

func updateUI() {
    label1.text = "aa"
    label2.text = "bb"
}
```

So just call your updateUI() function again after fetching data from API

Comment: Hi @Michał Kwiecień, My function already called  in viewDidLoad the problem is when I open my App the first time it open the view and then call the viewDidLoad then after some seconds when I receive data from server it doesn't call viewDidLoad because it needs to fresh or I need to go to another view  then to previews view in order to read viewDidLoad function

Comment: -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  //  [self showAlert];
    if (Support_three_ways_call){
        keypadEditorView.threewaysbutton.hidden = NO;
       
    
    } else {
    
        keypadEditorView.threewaysbutton.hidden = YES;
    }

} this code call when the bool value not receive from server when I open my App the first time it calls, the Support_three_ways_call   it is  bool value that come from server, so the first time when I open it shows false then from server it comes true but I have to refresh the view in order to show the button

Comment: which method u r calling for update UI from viewWillAppear?

Comment: I created the notification when receive value from server call my class viewWillApper  and also I tried setNeedsDisplay but it doesn't work, actually the code works but doest show the button because it needs to refresh